# Extruder motor not turning while printing, but works while testing on Ender 3

Tags: creality-ender-3, extruder

I have an Ender 3 with the silent board, BLTouch, and Marlin 2.0.6 installed. Recently I've the problem of the extruder not moving while printing, but works fine during testing. I tried changing the motherboard (that's when I installed the silent board) and changing the motor, but nothing worked. I usually use the CURA 5.3.0 slicer, but I also tried the Creality slicer and it still did not work. During print the extruder does not move, but it rocks back and forth during the initial purge before the print.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it was a bad cable. I just changed the cable.